# Can't persist and entity using JPA and H2 database - sql parameter isn't be set on sql statement

Tags: java, database, jpa, h2

I have a simple JPA example and I'm trying to write an entity to an H2 database.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#2" is not set; SQL statement:
insert into MyEntity (name, id) values (?, ?)`
```

Here is my code:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("thePersistenceUnit");
EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
manager.getTransaction().begin();
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.setName("heyyy");
manager.persist(entity);
manager.getTransaction().commit();
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    public MyEntity() {
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

my persistence unit

```
<persistence-unit name="thePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>io.tcell.MyEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:/tmp/myh2db"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: is working  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)?

Comment: @jklee no, AUTO doesn't work either.